# How can i use my splash screen until all data is loaded using a progressBar?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, splash-screen

In the splash screen i'm using now just for the demo a timer.
But i want to use a class that using win32 classes and wait until all loops are finished. While it's looping to make the progressBar move until 100%.

In form1 i didn't make yet anything.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestingHardware
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

In Program.cs i changed the Run:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestingHardware
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Splash_Screen());
        }
    }
}
```

Then i added a new form for the splash screen:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestingHardware
{
    public partial class Splash_Screen : Form
    {
        Timer tmr;

        public Splash_Screen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Splash_Screen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Splash_Screen_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tmr = new Timer();
            //set time interval 3 sec
            tmr.Interval = 3000;
            //starts the timer
            tmr.Start();
            tmr.Tick += tmr_Tick;
        }

        void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //after 3 sec stop the timer
            tmr.Stop();
            //display mainform
            Form1 mf = new Form1();
            mf.Show();
            //hide this form
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

In the splash screen form designer i added a progressBar.

And last the Form that get the hardware info. I want the splash screen and progressBar to shown while it's looping until the end.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Management;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GetHardwareInfo
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            cmbxOption.SelectedItem = "Win32_Processor";

        }

        private void InsertInfo(string Key, ref ListView lst, bool DontInsertNull)
        {
            lst.Items.Clear();

            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from " + Key);

            try
            {
                foreach (ManagementObject share in searcher.Get())
                {

                    ListViewGroup grp;
                    try
                    {
                        grp = lst.Groups.Add(share["Name"].ToString(), share["Name"].ToString());
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        grp = lst.Groups.Add(share.ToString(), share.ToString());
                    }

                    if (share.Properties.Count <= 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("No Information Available", "No Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        return;
                    }

                    foreach (PropertyData PC in share.Properties)
                    {

                        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(grp);
                        if (lst.Items.Count % 2 != 0)
                            item.BackColor = Color.White;
                        else
                            item.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;

                        item.Text = PC.Name;

                        if (PC.Value != null && PC.Value.ToString() != "")
                        {
                            switch (PC.Value.GetType().ToString())
                            {
                                case "System.String[]":
                                    string[] str = (string[])PC.Value;

                                    string str2 = "";
                                    foreach (string st in str)
                                        str2 += st + " ";

                                    item.SubItems.Add(str2);

                                    break;
                                case "System.UInt16[]":
                                    ushort[] shortData = (ushort[])PC.Value;


                                    string tstr2 = "";
                                    foreach (ushort st in shortData)
                                        tstr2 += st.ToString() + " ";

                                    item.SubItems.Add(tstr2);

                                    break;

                                default:
                                    item.SubItems.Add(PC.Value.ToString());
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (!DontInsertNull)
                                item.SubItems.Add("No Information available");
                            else
                                continue;
                        }
                        lst.Items.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            }


            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("can't get data because of the followeing error \n" + exp.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }


        }

        private void RemoveNullValue(ref ListView lst)
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem item in lst.Items)
                if (item.SubItems[1].Text == "No Information available")
                    item.Remove();
        }


        #region Control events ...

        private void cmbxNetwork_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InsertInfo(cmbxNetwork.SelectedItem.ToString(), ref lstNetwork, chkNetwork.Checked);
        }

        private void cmbxSystemInfo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InsertInfo(cmbxSystemInfo.SelectedItem.ToString(), ref lstSystemInfo, chkSystemInfo.Checked);
        }

        private void cmbxUtility_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InsertInfo(cmbxUtility.SelectedItem.ToString(), ref lstUtility, chkUtility.Checked);
        }

        private void cmbxUserAccount_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InsertInfo(cmbxUserAccount.SelectedItem.ToString(), ref lstUserAccount, chkUserAccount.Checked);
        }

        private void cmbxStorage_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InsertInfo(cmbxStorage.SelectedItem.ToString(), ref lstStorage, chkDataStorage.Checked);
        }

        private void cmbxDeveloper_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InsertInfo(cmbxDeveloper.SelectedItem.ToString(), ref lstDeveloper, chkDeveloper.Checked);
        }

        private void cmbxMemory_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InsertInfo(cmbxMemory.SelectedItem.ToString(), ref lstMemory, chkMemory.Checked);
        }

        private void chkHardware_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (chkHardware.Checked)
                RemoveNullValue(ref lstDisplayHardware);
            else
                InsertInfo(cmbxOption.SelectedItem.ToString(), ref lstDisplayHardware, chkHardware.Checked);
        }

        private void cmbxOption_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InsertInfo(cmbxOption.SelectedItem.ToString(), ref lstDisplayHardware, chkHardware.Checked);
        }

        private void chkDataStorage_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (chkDataStorage.Checked)
                RemoveNullValue(ref lstStorage);
            else
                InsertInfo(cmbxStorage.SelectedItem.ToString(), ref lstStorage, chkDataStorage.Checked);
        }

        private void chkMemory_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (chkMemory.Checked)
                RemoveNullValue(ref lstMemory);
            else
                InsertInfo(cmbxMemory.SelectedItem.ToString(), ref lstStorage, false);
        }

        private void chkSystemInfo_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (chkSystemInfo.Checked)
                RemoveNullValue(ref lstSystemInfo);
            else
                InsertInfo(cmbxSystemInfo.SelectedItem.ToString(), ref lstSystemInfo, false);
        }

        private void chkNetwork_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (chkNetwork.Checked)
                RemoveNullValue(ref lstNetwork);
            else
                InsertInfo(cmbxNetwork.SelectedItem.ToString(), ref lstNetwork, false);
        }

        private void chkUserAccount_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (chkUserAccount.Checked)
                RemoveNullValue(ref lstUserAccount);
            else
                InsertInfo(cmbxUserAccount.SelectedItem.ToString(), ref lstUserAccount, false);
        }

        private void chkDeveloper_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (chkDeveloper.Checked)
                RemoveNullValue(ref lstDeveloper);
            else
                InsertInfo(cmbxDeveloper.SelectedItem.ToString(), ref lstDeveloper, false);
        }

        private void chkUtility_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (chkUtility.Checked)
                RemoveNullValue(ref lstUtility);
            else
                InsertInfo(cmbxUtility.SelectedItem.ToString(), ref lstUtility, false);
        }

        private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            linkLabel1.LinkVisited = true;
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.ShiraziOnline.net");
        }

        #endregion


    }
}
```

It's using win32 classes and instead adding it to a ListView i want to add each part to a List. Then i want to use the Lists in form1 when it's finishing all loops and add the Lists to controls. Or maybe i should load it in form1 already ?
Not sure.

Comment: You need to update the ProgressBar.Value to a value between 0 and 100. So inorder to do this you will need to know how many items are in total and which item you are currently on. Also, call ProgressBar.Refresh() to update the control.

Answer (score 0):

If searcher has a Count property, use that for your maximum value. Determine current percentage with:

```
        int count = 0;
        try
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject share in searcher.Get())
            {
                count++;
                progressbar1.Value = count * 100 / Math.Max(1, searcher.Count);
```

Also, make sure that you are setting your ListView to suspend updates using .SuspendLayout() before adding the items and .ResumeLayout() afterwards as constantly updating your ListView is very slow.
Another recommendation would be to place all your ListViewItems into an List/Array and then just update your ListView once.

Create a List at the start just after the Clear()

```
        lst.SuspendLayout();
        lst.Items.Clear()
        System.Collections.Generic.List<ListViewItem> listViewItems = new System.Collections.Generic.List<ListViewItem>();
```

Then where you were adding the items before add them to the List<>

```
        listViewItems.Add(item);
```

And finally after all records have been processed add the List<> to your ListView and resume updates

```
        try
        {
            // All your code here

            lst.Items.AddRange(listViewItems.ToArray());
        }
        finally
        {
            lst.ResumeLayout();
        }
```

Comment: There is no property IndexOf for searcher.

Comment: Just use a count variable that increments on each for loop and use that instead then.